# Missing Geoprocessing Tools in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I recently reformatted my hard drive, so I downloaded QGIS so I could install it again. But now that I have, I seem to be missing all of my geoprocessing tools. Normally there were quite a few available from the drop-down Vector menu. Now there are only a handful. Also, I can't find the processing toolbox that I used to use, not sure what that was called but it seems to be missing now. It was where you could access all of the geoprocessing commands including GRASS.

Comment: Have you searched the plugins list?

Comment: Pressed Ctrl-Alt-T to get the processing pane?

Comment: What OS, what QIS version are you running? Can you start the plugin manager? If not, python support is broken.

Comment: Yes I've searched the plugins list it seems like not everything is available. I've tried Ctrl-Alt-T with no result. I have windows 10 and the installed qgis is 2.18.10. The plugin manager works, it's not showing any plugins as installed though.